# What are the most essential rules in D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players

I want to create a quick reference sheet for new players in my D&D 5e campaign. Sessions include an even mix of combat, exploration, and social situations, so the sheet should ideally deal with all three.

What would be a sensible list of rules (and other guidance) for first time players to have on hand?

*Answers might include reference to an example of such a sheet online, but should not only include a link to one, as I want to create my own.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The group I use this with:

I run organized play at a boarding high school: almost all my kids come into a year unfamiliar with D&D. Our sessions tend to be 1/2 social, 1/4 exploration, 1/4 combat, 'cause the kids really like chatting with the town drunk, trying to intimidate yetis, and the like.

That said, the times they get tripped up on rules and need a quick reference almost always occur during combat. Thus I've put together a half-page reference sheet based off of the things that tend to trip up my kids:

### Player's Reference

- Ability/Skill checks
- Combat

  - intiative/surprise
  - on your turn: move, action, bonus action, talk, interact
  - on another's turn: reaction, opportunity attack, readied action
  - movement rules
  - actions: attack, cast, dash, disengage, dodge, help, hide, ready, use an object, *anything else you think of!*
  - attack rules
- Damage: track current HP separate from HP max, instant death, death saves, stability
- (Dis)advantage
- Resting

  - short rest: >=1hr + >0HP; at end may spend hit dice to regain HP, *class features*
  - long rest: >=8hr, >0HP; at end regain all HP, spell slots, *class features*
- Saving throws

Each item gets a line or two, if necessary and I fit it all on the top half of an A4 sheet, in 3 columns. For example, here's the entry for "ability/skill checks":

[image: ability/skill check description]

I'm happy to send it along to you if you'd like to see the full example. Pop into [chat] and you're more likely than not to find me.

Answer (score 1):

## Consider purchasing Game Master's Screen. It has a summary of rules on one side.

I have seen a few quick reference sheets, some of them were really nice and I don't think that creating a new one will be a necessity.

## A good quick reference sheet will definitely need more space than just one page

Unless you are thinking about a A3 format page, printed on both sides. Then, it could do.

It should include:

- Key mechanics (Advantage/disadvantage, resistance, vulnerability)
- Skills and their key abilities
- Character stats
- Combat rules
- Magic basic rules
- Dying, Healing and Resting
- Conditions summary
- Falling, Exhaustion and Suffocating
- Light
- Travelling
- Traps

The shortest one I could find is 3 pages long, but it covers what the player could forget about.

[Vertical](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byr-i7lu1I5ISzU4SHNuTHhHNXc/view)

[Horizontal](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byr-i7lu1I5IaW1kSWNENWdyNHc/view)

If you think, it might be needed, you can add table with equipment, weapons and armors.